# Animate UIView on tilt

Tags: ios, swift, animation, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to animate a Mapview (Mapbox) depending on the tilt of the iPhone. When the angle is bigger than 45 degrees the MapView should animate to a circle centred at the bottom, when the angle is lower than 45 degrees the MapView should expand to fill the whole screen.

I'm using animations with Constraints. The animation is not working how it supposed to be: [Gif of the Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODQEd.gif)

This is the code I use:

```
if value > 45 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.mapView.frame = CGRect(x: self.mapViewInitialX, y: self.mapViewInitialY, width: 200, height: 200)
            self.mapviewBottomConstraint.constant = 15
            self.mapViewWidthConstraint.constant = 200
            self.mapViewHeightConstraint.constant = 200
            self.mapView.layer.cornerRadius = 100
            self.mapView.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            self.mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (self.mapView.superview?.bounds.width)!, height: (self.mapView.superview?.bounds.height)!)
            self.mapviewBottomConstraint.constant = 0
            self.mapViewWidthConstraint.constant = (self.mapView.superview?.bounds.width)!
            self.mapViewHeightConstraint.constant = (self.mapView.superview?.bounds.height)!
            self.mapView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
            self.mapView.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
```

Comment: You should change constants outside (before) of animation block, so in animation block layoutifNeeded will come. And what is your expected result ?

Comment: Alright, I will do that. The animation from circle to full screen works fine. Just the other way round is not correct. It starts somewhere off screen and moves to that position. It should go from full screen back to circle at the bottom.